# [recovery]: remove or recover?

Tags: discussion, tags

There is at the moment a [single question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37112/how-can-a-server-recover-from-its-secret-key-stolen) with the tag [recovery](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recovery). The meaning of the tag is recovering from a security breach. It's a bit like [incident-response](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/incident-response), but covering the aftermath rather than the immediate reaction.

Earlier today, there were a couple more questions with that tag, which were about recovering a forgotten password. I retagged them.

On the one hand, this meaning of [recovery](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recovery) seems reasonable. On the other hand, it's surprising that we'd end up with a single question about that topic. Is there a synonym that I've missed? Should we just use [incident-response](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/incident-response) for everything? Should there be more questions tagged [recovery](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recovery)?

Answer (score 5):

Recovery should be a well used tag in business continuity or disaster recovery, however in looking for recovery type questions under [incident-response](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/incident-response) there really isn't much. This suggests to me that maybe we have trimmed it down to:

> Nuke it from orbit. It's the only way to be sure

Which is our general response. I think if we have more **proper** aftermath questions, ie the how we recover, what do we bring online first, how do we focus efforts after an attack or a natural disaster or even a systems failure, then the [recovery](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recovery)  tag may be more useful.

Comment: I agree. recovery would make much more sense from a DR/BCP perspective.

Comment: “Nuke it from orbit” only makes sense after a breach of integrity, and even then it's not the full story: you may need to e.g. revoke signatures. Recovering after a breach of confidentiality (as in [the question](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37112/how-can-a-server-recover-from-its-secret-key-stolen)) is a different matter.

Comment: Oh, I agree - this question is definitely the **right** kind for the tag. My comment about nuking from orbit is that that so far is our usual answer for the types of questions we get (my box got hax0red - what nao?)

Comment: so wouldnt [tag:disaster-recovery] be more appropriate (and specific) here? Or is the issue that it wasnt an actual "natural" disaster... And for that matter, is this not still within the scope of [tag:incident-response]?

Answer (score 0):

If we want a tag for systems for recovering a lost/forgotten password, I suggest creating a new tag like [password-recovery](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/password-recovery) -- not trying to re-purpose [recovery](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recovery) for that.

[recovery](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recovery) seems to me like it's probably OK for questions on recovering from system compromise, but [incident-response](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/incident-response) would also be OK: I have no opinion on choosing between those two.